# Can't bind custom control content (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, path, resources

I have a trivial custom control based on Button:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ArrowButton}">

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>

    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ArrowButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It does not have any significant C# code:

```
public class ArrowButton : Button, IDisposable
{
    static ArrowButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ArrowButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ArrowButton)));
    }
}
```

If I use this control (inside some UserControl) in the following way, it works fine (I got two buttons with black triangles):

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:ArrowButton">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <local:ArrowButton Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Black" Data="M  0 0 L 0 20 L 10 10 Z"/>
    </local:ArrowButton>
    <local:ArrowButton Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Black" Data="M  0 0 L 0 20 L 10 10 Z"/>
    </local:ArrowButton>
```

but if I move my Path to a StaticResource than I got a strange effect: only the last button has the black triangle and all other buttons on the UserConltrol remain empty (looks like the Path bound only once).

```
    <Grid.Resources>
    <Path x:Key="ArrowPath" Fill="Black" Data="M  0 0 L 0 20 L 10 10 Z"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <local:ArrowButton Content="{StaticResource ArrowPath}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <local:ArrowButton Content="{StaticResource ArrowPath}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Any ideas, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [`x:Shared="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when declaring the `Path` resource:

```
<Path x:Key="ArrowPath" x:Shared="False" Fill="Black" Data="M  0 0 L 0 20 L 10 10 Z"/>
```

Otherwise, the same `Path` object will be used, which will change the `Path`'s visual parent over and over again (until it stops for the last `ArrowButton`). Setting `x:Shared="False"` will create a new instance of the `Path` object each time it's consumed, which will solve your problem.

Make sure you also read the restrictions on where `x:Shared` can be used in WPF, listed at the bottom of the linked page.